# How to pass props/params/state to a Route with Link in React Router 5.2.0?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I've tried a lot of examples from React Router documentation, Stackoverflow answers and posts on the web, but couldn't get anything working.

Here's what I have now:

```
<Link to={{
   pathname: "/project",
   state: { id: "id0" }
}}>Passing Props</Link>
```

and

```
<Route path="/project" component={Project}  />
```

and state is undefined here:

```
function Project(params) {
  console.log("passprops");
  console.log(params);
// state is undefined in params
```

I've also tried passing with "/project/:id" and render={(props) =>  } but it didn't work too.

How to pass props/params/state to a Route with Link in React Router 5.2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from my project

```js
<Link to="/project/id1">Project</Link>



<Route path="/project/:id" component={Project}/>



function Project() {
  let { id } = useParams();
}
```

Comment: How do your Link and UserRecords look like? Is this working with Router 5.2.0?

Comment: exactly with "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2", but i don't think that they made some major changes between 5.1 and 5.2... :)
[git hub repo](https://github.com/robert8888/djtruck/blob/master/src/router/Routes.js) it is the most beautiful code, but working :) hooby project.

Comment: im using useParams() from react router dom in userRecods

Comment: this doesn't work for me, it opens the main page instead of the /project: <Link to={"/project/yo"}>Passing Props</Link>
        <Route
          path="/project/:id"
          exact
          render={(props) => (
            <Project searchQuery={props.match.params} {...props} />
          )}
        />

Comment: and how looks project ? you don't get nothing on props.searchQuery ? do you try use useParams() ? \

Comment: if you have time you can reproduce minimal veriosn of problem on (https://codesandbox.io/) turn on chat post link and then we can together looking for solution.

Comment: I've added the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-link-pass-props-s1w0m?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: i just change <Link path="/project/myuniqid".... => <Link to="/project/myuniqid".... and seems to work

Comment: @Darkhan (https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-link-pass-props-forked-0fnij)

Comment: thanks to you I've fixed this and a couple of other bugs and it works fine now!